# How do you read the values of individual features from a FeatureField in Lucene?

Tags: lucene

I'm using Lucene 7.6.0 and I've indexed a series of documents with a `FeatureField` named "features", that stores query-independent evidence (e.g., "indegree", "pagerank"). If I'm not mistaken, the theory is that these are stored as a term vector, where "indegree" and "pagerank" are stored as terms and their values are stored as the corresponding term frequencies.

I've tested some queries where I combined BM25 and each individual feature, and some return a different ranking, when compared to BM25 alone, but some others seem to have no effect. This might just be a coincidence, which is fine, but I would like to check whether the values were correctly indexed. How do I do this?

I've tried using Luke to inspect the index, but there is no term vector associated with the "features" field. The active flags for "features" are only "Idf", but I honestly can't find a way to access the frequencies for each document. The best I was able to do, in order to check whether the field had any value, was something like:

```
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(
    FSDirectory.open(Paths.get("/tmp/lucene-index")));
reader.totalTermFreq(new Term("features", "indegree"));
```

This printed the number 33344, which does not match the value I indexed (a single document with indegree 10), however I suspect this might be codified somehow.

I know this API is still experimental, but I was wondering if anyone knew if it would be possible to retrieve the feature values, either for each document or globally somehow (maybe an anonymous vector, without a link to the corresponding documents).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to verify the that the ranking by each feature matches the order for the data that I have. I also believe I was able to fairly reverse the provided relevance score to obtain the original feature value (I say "fairly", because I found what seem to be slightly rounding errors; let me know if it's an error instead). The code I used was the following:

```
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(
    FSDirectory.open(Paths.get("/tmp/lucene-index")));

IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
searcher.setSimilarity(new BM25Similarity(1.2f, 0.75f));

float w = 1.8f;
float k = 1f;
float a = 0.6f;

Query query = FeatureField.newSigmoidQuery("features", "indegree", w, k, a);
TopDocs hits = searcher.search(query, 5);

for (int i = 0; i < hits.scoreDocs.length; i++) {
    Document doc = searcher.doc(hits.scoreDocs[i].doc);
    float featureValue = (float) Math.pow(
        (hits.scoreDocs[i].score / w * Math.pow(k, a))
            / (1 - hits.scoreDocs[i].score / w),
        1 / a
    );
    System.out.println(featureValue + "\t" + doc.get("doc_id"));
}

reader.close();
```

The equation for `featureValue` is simply the sigmoid scaling of the static feature `S` (the "indegree" in this case) solved for `S`, based on the relevance score. You can find the original equation in the paper cited in Lucene's JavaDoc for `FeatureField`: https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1076034.1076106

Please let me know if you find any error with this solution, or if there is an easier way to inspect the index.